# Unsupported type 'delimiter'

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated my android studio to latest version (3.0) few days ago .
I worked with my old android projects without any problem.

But today for the first time after updated to new version I created a new project(new Java project).when I try to run it, it shows this error.

> Error:Error: Unsupported type 'delimiter'

I cleaned and rebuild the project but it didn't work.

I can see this on the Gradle console

> *What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> C:\Users\Asoft.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\51aeb15d71de80d9c27043b97bce9776\res\values\values.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'delimiter'

This is what I can see in the messages

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> C:\Users\Asoft.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\51aeb15d71de80d9c27043b97bce9776\res\values\values.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'delimiter'
>   Error:Error: Unsupported type 'delimiter'

Comment: Can you give more detail? Is there something in IDE console? Try to rebuild project and check your xml resources

Comment: Check this one `\values‌​\values.xml` . Maybe there is an unsupported character or something

Comment: I can see @delimiter in many places of values.xml. Should I delete them?

Comment: Can you please post it in the question?

Comment: Please try to use File | Invalidate Caches/Restart -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cleaning-system-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a possible solution

I followed the path given on the error message

C:\Users\Asoft.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\51aeb15d71de80d9c27043b97bce9776\res\values\values.xml

and deleted the file.

After a clean and build the app started running without any error.